# How to receive data sent using ajax call by Post method in MVC4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to send my ajax data through post method, from my view but I don't how to receive it in the controller method. here is ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    method: 'post',
    async: false,
    url: "Gateway/DB_Rola",
    data:Obj,
    success: function (Data) {alert("Good");},
    error: function () {alert("Error");}
});
```

Here is controller code :

```
[HttpPost]                // bindig data with class thing
public JsonResult DB_Rola(thing things)
{ ... }
```

modal class code :

```
public class thing
{
    public int surah { get; set; }
    public int ayah { get; set; }
    public string verse { get; set; }
}
```

Now I don't know how to get that object in controller method. I have tried it with `get` method , there its working fine, problem is with `post`...

Comment: What is `Obj` in `data:Obj` and why the query-string `count`?

Comment: i have edited the code, its json object..

Comment: Have you tried with the code, which was given by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var things = new Object();
        things.surah = 1;
        things.ayah = 2;
        things.verse = "3";
        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/DB_Rola?count=" + 1,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(things),
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('boo!');
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

**MODEL**

```
public class thing
{
    public int surah { get; set; }
    public int ayah { get; set; }
    public string verse { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DB_Rola(thing things)
    {
        return Json(new { IsSuccess = true });
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

**With/Without Count**

[image]
[image]

Update 1 : pass the list[] of objects instead of single object things

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var things = new Array();
        var test1 = new Object();
        test1.surah = 1;
        test1.ayah = 2;
        test1.verse = "3";
        things.push(test1);
        var test2 = new Object();
        test2.surah = 11;
        test2.ayah = 22;
        test2.verse = "33";
        things.push(test2);
        $.ajax({
            url: "Home/DB_Rola?count=" + 1,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(things),
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('boo!');
            },
        });
    });
</script>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DB_Rola(List<thing> things,int count)
{
      return Json(new { IsSuccess = true });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much @jayesh for this effort, its working now .! :)

Comment: could you please guide what to do if i want to pass the list[] of objects instead of single object things, any changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this It's just an Example,

```
function SearchProduct () {
  var isExcluded = $('#chkisExcluded').is(':checked');

      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  '@Url.Action("SearchProductManagement","ProductListManagement")',
                data: { isExcluded: isExcluded,},
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
 });
}
```

**Controller**

```
   public JsonResult SearchProductManagement(bool isExcluded)
        {
 //Your code
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);         
}
```

**View**

```
 <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="return SearchProduct();" class="button next" />
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming `Obj = {surah:somvalue, ayah:somevalue, verse:somevalue}`
The problem is the extra parameter count, you don't have a post action that handles count,
so try:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    method: 'post',
    async: false,
    url: "Gateway/DB_Rola,
    data:Obj,
    success: function (Data) {alert("Good");},
    error: function () {alert("Error");}
});
```

Comment: its still not working, and tell me how to receive it in controller ?